# Кроссбраузерное определение события прокрутки колесика мыши

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

Проблема состоит в следующем: В хроме и опере работает все просто прекрасно, а вот мозилла и сафари возвращают или undefined или не аргумент, который передается в функцию в момент события. Точнее аргумент они понимают, но возвращают его как undefined.  Если вставить console.log()  в саму функцию, то я вижу цифры (что мне как раз и нужно), но вне функции она превращается в undefined. Я явно чего-то недопонимаю.... Помогите, плиз ))

Использовал Два варианта
№1

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('wrapper-circus');

if (elem.addEventListener) {
  if ('onwheel' in document) {
    // IE9+, FF17+

    elem.addEventListener("wheel", onWheel);
    var myNum = onWheel();
  } else if ('onmousewheel' in document) {
    // устаревший вариант события

    elem.addEventListener("mousewheel", onWheel());
    var myNum = onWheel();
  } else {
    // Firefox < 17

    elem.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", onWheel());
    var myNum = onWheel();
  }
} else { // IE8-

  elem.attachEvent("onmousewheel", onWheel());
  var myNum = onWheel();
}


// Это решение предусматривает поддержку IE8-
function onWheel(e) {

  if (e !== undefined) {

    // deltaY, detail содержат пиксели
    // wheelDelta не дает возможность узнать количество пикселей
    // onwheel || MozMousePixelScroll || onmousewheel

    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : (e.returnValue = false);
    var delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;
    return delta;

  }

  e = e || window.event;
  if (e != undefined) {

    var delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;
    console.log(delta);
    return delta * 100;
  }

}
```

№2

```js
//Переменные
var delta; // Направление колёсика мыши
//Объявление переменной значения зума

//Функция для добавления обработчика событий
function addHandler(object, event, handler) {
  if (object.addEventListener) {
    object.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
  } else if (object.attachEvent) {
    object.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
  } else alert("Обработчик не поддерживается");
}

// Добавляем обработчики для разных браузеров
addHandler(window, 'DOMMouseScroll', wheel);
addHandler(window, 'mousewheel', wheel);
addHandler(document, 'mousewheel', wheel);

// Функция, обрабатывающая событие
function wheel(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  // Opera и IE работают со свойством wheelDelta
  if (event.wheelDelta) { // В Opera и IE
    delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
    // В Опере значение wheelDelta такое же, но с противоположным знаком
    if (window.opera) {
      delta = -delta; // Дополнительно для Opera
    }
  } else if (event.detail) { // Для Gecko
    delta = -event.detail / 3;
  }
  // Запрещаем обработку события браузером по умолчанию
  if (event.preventDefault) {
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    event.returnValue = false; //Для ослика
  }


}
```

В гугле, естественно, я смотрел. Но может быть, что не туда смотрел...
Всем спасибо огромное.

Comment: А что вообще должно происходить, какого результата вы хотите добиться, для чего вам это нужно?

Comment: Слайдер. Прокрутка колесом блока с картинками. вправо, если они есть, и обратно в начало
Хочу получать положительное значение, если крутят вниз и отрицательное, если вверх